# Is it possible to see room noise?

Tags: adobe, audition, equalization

In Adobe Audition, using any of the visualisation/analysis tools, is is it possible to see and isolate, then remove room/background noise?

Was wondering if there are certain frequencies that human voice operates within thus allowing the rest to be minimised or deleted.

Answer (score 2):

Audition has specialized tools that allow you to isolate and remove noise. Have you looked at the official documentation? (Especially the capture noise print/remove noise combo)

https://helpx.adobe.com/audition/how-to/remove-noise-audio-files.html[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, I think I should have asked: Are there bands in EQ that can be safely quashed that are outside of human voice. Thinking that if noise is not human noise it must be room/background noise.

Comment: Thee are some specific frequencies that human voice resides on. You can do a search for the details. However it is not that simple. First of all male and female voices differ. And the ranges themselves are pretty wide. Your best bet is to play around with all ranges and listen yourself for improvements.